# Why cookieParser doesnt return value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I'm using vue, vue-router for my client-side and express, morgan for my server side (MEVN app)

So, at the client i'm setting cookies by using vue-cookies

```
this.$cookies.set('Login', this.login, new Date(Date.now() + 86400 * 5 * 1000))
this.$cookies.set('Password', this.password, new Date(Date.now() + 86400 * 5 * 1000))
```

And at the server side i'm using cookieParser

So, at app.js i have such a code

```
const express       = require('express');
const morgan        = require('morgan');
const cors          = require('cors');
const bodyParser    = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser  = require('cookie-parser');

const config        = require('./config/config');
const db            = require('./controllers/DB');
const mCLogs        = require('./modelControllers/Logs');
const mCLogin       = require('./modelControllers/Login');

const app = express();
app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser()); /*cookie parser*/
```

And, at the file `./modelControllers/Login` i have such a code for a GET request

```
    exports.checkLoginSession = async (req, res, next) => {
/*its not all of the code*/
        var loginHash = req.cookies['Login'];
        console.log(loginHash)
        if(loginHash == undefined) {
            res.send({
                logged: false,
                description: "err mes"
            });
        } else {
            res.send({
                logged: true,
                description: "mes"
            });
        }
    }
```

and the problem is that the `var loginHash = req.cookies['Login'];` always return undefined, even when i have "Login" cookie

Addition:
How i call this method:

Client-side and using axios

```
mounted () {
    this.getLoginData()
  },
  methods: {
    async getLoginData () {
      const response = await LoginHandler.checkUserLoginSession()
      if (response.data.logged === true) {
        this.$router.push('/')
      } else {
        this.errorMessage = response.data.description
      }
    }
}
```

LoginHandler.js(client side)

import api from '@/services/api'

```
export default {
  checkUserLoginSession () {
    return api().get('/login')
  }
}
```

Server-side /login link in app.js

```
app.get('/login', mCLogin.checkLoginSession);
app.post('/login', mCLogin.checkUserData);
```

ADDITION:

It doesnt work when i use such a code with axios API:

import api from '@/services/api'

```
export default {
  checkUserLoginSession () {
    return api().get('/login')
  }
}
```

So, when i call `checkUserLoginSession` app.get('/login') return cookie value undefined, but, if i open link in browser (serverside) localhost:3000/login it's returning correct value

Addition: checkUserData

```
exports.checkUserData = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let login = req.body.login;
        let password = req.body.password;

        const user = await db.users.findOne({
            where: {
                Login: login,
                Password: password
            }
        });
        if(user == null)
        {
            res.send({
                logged: false,
                description: "Пользователь не найден."
            });
            return;
        }
        if(user.dataValues.Login == login && user.dataValues.Password == password)
        {
            res.send({
                logged: true,
                description: "Авторизация произошла успешно. Сейчас Вас перенаправит!"
            });
            return;
        }
    }
    catch(ex) {
        res.send({
            logged: false,
            description: "Произошла ошибка на стороне сервера."
        });
        console.log(ex);
        return;
    }
```

### }

If i add `withCredentials: true` to axios.create, server return cookie value, but i've this errors on console line

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/login' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

Comment: You're probably not sending the cookies in the programmatic request (i.e. `checkUserLoginSession()`), but the browser sends all cookies automatically in a get request made through the address bar.

Comment: checkUserLoginSession() only recieve json response from serverside (check the code)
and mCLogin.checkLoginSession reads cookie, but cant find it, even if they are setted, so i always get json response that i'm not authorized

Comment: Can you post the code from: `mCLogin.checkUserData` function?

Comment: Yea, sure. But its not connected with a problem (i hope)

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys, i solve my issue.

So, the answer is.

1. Change `LoginHandler` code:

From:

```
import api from '@/services/api'

export default {
  checkUserLoginSession () {
    return api().get('/login')
  }
}
```

To:

```
import api from '@/services/api'

export default {
  checkUserLoginSession () {
    return api().get('/login', {withCredentials: true})
  }
}
```

2. Change `app.js`

From:

```
app.use(cors());
```

To:

```
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:8080" }));
```

3. Change method `checkLoginSession`

To:

```
exports.checkLoginSession = (req, res, next) => {
    const { Login, Password } = req.cookies;
    //Where Login, Password ... is your cookie name
    //console.log(Login)
    if(Login == undefined) {
        res.send({
            logged: false,
            description: "Нет сохранённых хешей для авторизации!"
        });
    } else {
        res.send({
            logged: true,
            description: "Авторизован."
        });
    }
}
```

P.S Thanks to all, who tried to help me